# conditional beforeUpdate in sails

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I need to encrypt the password only if some criteria is fullfilled.

```
beforeUpdate: function (value, cb) {
User.findOne(value.id)
  .exec(function (err, originalUser) {
    if (err || !originalUser) {
      return cb();
    }
    //encrypt the password only if the password is not previously encrypted
    if (value.password != originalUser.password) {
       //encrypt the Pwd
    } else {
      cb();
    }
  });
```

}
The problem is that, the value object only contains the update params, how can I get the whole user object in the value object?

Comment: Not sure if I am able to understand clearly, but why do you need the other params which are not being updated. They will be same as in the originalUser.

Comment: Isnt the whole user object already there in the `originalUser` already ?

Comment: nope, as the value.id is undefined..

Comment: Can you please do a console.log(value) in the beforeUpdate ?

Comment: Now I got your problem. Trying a solution

Comment: You should post this question on sails google groups

Comment: Else you can always override the update action in the controller

Comment: I'm very disappointed in sails, there should be a way to access the entire original object

Answer (score 5):

> After the update of async, this method does not work anymore.

You can not get the whole object inside `beforeUpdate`. You can try this to get the id. 
`var id= this.update.arguments[0]`

Comment: Beware - no longer works because of changes in async, which waterline uses.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on what user3036010 suggested, I ended up creating a new policy like this:

In `api/policies/propagateId.js`:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.param('id');
    if (id && req.body) {
        req.body.id = id;
    }

    next();
};
```

Then set up your `api/config/policies.js` file to apply the policy by default to all controllers and actions:

```
module.exports.policies = {
    '*': 'propagateId'
};
```

What this does is it forces the `id` property to be set on the document body, which tricks the update action into thinking that the `id` was manually specified.  For whatever reason, there is a block of code in the update action that checks for this, and if the `id` is not manually specified it will remove it from the values.

This is sort of an abuse of policies, but it seems to work fine for me.  If you don't want to do it this way, it looks like manually specifying `id` in your request body every time you make an update API request should work too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need this in the value object here, but you may create a custom policy that will get the whole user object and send in 'next()' callback to update;

Comment: Any idea or example on how can I do it?

Comment: @taufique See the answer I just posted, which is an example that works for me.

Comment: @taufique See my answer for quick fix

Answer (score 1):

Just use lodash to extend value with originalUser. Or for this use case you can always just check if the pasword is already hashed if you using node bcrypt or something

Answer (score 1):

Now, only if you send password: password in the Update method, it will update the password (hash and store) else it will only update the provided user fields.

Controller(UserController.js):

```
updateDisplayName: function(req, res) {

var userid = req.token;
var newDisplayName = req.param('newdisplayname');

User.update({id: userid},{displayname: newDisplayName}).exec(function afterwards(err,updated){

if (err) {
res.json(err);
} else {
res.json("Success");
}
});

},
```

Model(User.js):

```
beforeUpdate: function(values, next) {
if(values.password) {
hashPassword(values, next);
} else {
next();
}
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying to do something similar: save the password to the associated passport record.  I'm using the sails-auth and sails-permissions modules, which includes passport.

I was finally able to do it by using the afterValidate [lifecycle callback](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks) instead of beforeUpdate callback.  In the afterValidate callback, you can access the user model using `this.user`.

Here's the code I put into my afterValidate callback where I save the password passed in using the Passport model:

```
afterValidate: function(updates, next) {
  // Update the passport password if it was passed in
  if(updates.password) {
    Passport.update({user: this.user.id}, {password: updates.password}).exec(function(err, passport) {
      next(err);
    });
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
}
```